# Formally Proving $1$ is the supremum of $(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I'm just getting used to doing very formal proofs in real analysis, and this problem has stumped me in terms of formulating a proof:

> Prove, or disprove, that $1$ is the supremum of $(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

It's intuitively clear that $1$ is the least upper bound of $A = (0, 1)$; $1$ is at the very "edge" of this interval, and even if you go an infinitesimally small amount below $1$, it's still inside $A$ and less than $1,$ which is sup $A$. But, how do I prove this formally? I tried using an epsilon definition, but I seem to be going in circles. Any help would be great.

Also, how does one become better at doing these "simple" but formal proofs? I seem to struggle with proving things as seemingly easy as "prove that $a * 0$ = $0$ in a field". Thank you.

Comment: regarding your last sentence: some of these proofs are "so easy"  they "become hard." the point is that these proofs in general do not require "ideas," but are instead implementations of axioms etc. which is a pretty different way of thinking. Probably you get better at them by better understanding the definitions of the objects your'e dealing with.

Comment: How is it intuitively clear to you that 1 is the least upper bound of $A$? I have never seen people framing their intuitive thoughts into words. Once you do  that you will have found the proof. Formal proofs are not so much different from one's intuitive thoughts, they just focus on reducing ambiguity as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $x\in(0,1)$, $x\leqslant1$. Therefore, $1$ is an upper bound of $(0,1)$.

And if $x<1$, if $x<0$, then $x$ is not an upper bound of $(0,1)$. Otherwise, $x<\frac{x+1}2\in(0,1)$, which, again, proves that $x$ is not an upper bound of $(0,1)$.

So, $1$ is the least upper bound of $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $s$ is the supremum of some set $A$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $a \in A$ so that $s-a<\epsilon$.

Specializing: let $s=1$, and consider $1-\frac{1}{n} \in  (0,1)$ for each $ n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

As Andres Mejia said, consider que set $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:0<x<1\}$.

By definition, $\alpha =Sup(A)$ if and only if

1. $\alpha$ is the upper bound of $A$ and
2. $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists a_0\in A (\alpha-\epsilon<a_0)$.

By definition of set $A$, $\forall x\in A, x<1$, so $1$ es an upper bound of $A$.
We need now to prove 2). Let $\alpha = 1$. Suppose that $\epsilon >0$. We want to find $a_0 \in A$ such that $\alpha-\epsilon<a_0$. This means that $1-\epsilon<a_0$.

Thus $\epsilon>0$, by the archimedean property, $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}<\epsilon$ therefore, $-\epsilon < -\frac{1}{n_0}$ and therefore $1-\epsilon < 1-\frac{1}{n_0}$, which means that $a_0=1-\frac{1}{n_0}$ just as Andres said.

$\therefore Sup(A)=1$.

Same thing happens with infimum.